# Multiple checkboxes in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, checkbox, xcode4.5

I need to add multiple checkboxes in each `UITableViewCell`. I knew how to do it if there is only one checkbox and we check the status. But as I take multiple checkboxes, checkbox status is not getting correctly. I can check the checkbox when I click on it twice.

```
-(IBAction)checkboxClicked:(id)sender
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)
                              [[sender superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"The section  is %d",  indexPath.section);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *cellSection = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int tagID=[sender tag];

    int divnum=0;
    if(tagID<100)
        divnum=10;
    else
        divnum=100;
    int section=[sender tag]/divnum;
    section-=1;
    int itemId=[sender tag]%divnum;

    if(itemId==selectedrowforCheckBox)
    {

        if(self.isChecked ==NO)
        {
            self.isChecked =YES;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemId];
            int m=[cellSection count]-1;
            NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

            NSMutableDictionary *hk=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [hk setObject:xWrapped forKey:@"Ans"];
            [hk setObject:questionId forKey:@"QId"];
            [selectedOptionandQIdArray addObject:hk];
         }
       else
        {
            self.isChecked =NO;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemId];
            int m=[cellSection count]-1;
            NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

            for (int i=0;i<[selectedOptionandQIdArray count];i++)
            {

                NSString *qid=[[selectedOptionandQIdArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"QId"];
                if(xWrapped==[[selectedOptionandQIdArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Ans"] && [questionId isEqualToString:qid])
                {

                    NSLog(@"nnd");
                    [selectedOptionandQIdArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];                        
                }
            }
        }
        selectedrowforCheckBox=itemId; 
    }
    else
    {
        if(self.isChecked ==NO)
        {
            self.isChecked =YES;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            NSNumber* xWrapped = [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemId];
            int m=[cellSection count]-1;
            NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

            NSMutableDictionary *hk=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [hk setObject:xWrapped forKey:@"Ans"];
            [hk setObject:questionId forKey:@"QId"];


            [selectedOptionandQIdArray addObject:hk];



        }
        else
        {
            self.isChecked =NO;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        selectedrowforCheckBox=itemId;
    }
}
```

Where Am I going wrong? How to handle multiple checkboxes in `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: when u click on it once check ur selectedrowforCheckBox value..if it doesnt return anything then u need to first get selectedrowforCheckBox from didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then fire above code from there itself.

Comment: can you post a picture? multiple check boxes sounds like a bad idea at first...

Answer (score 0):

you try this

1 you give the tags all your CheckBoxes and cell of rows and view on cellForRowAtIndexPath
 2 and on click button you try write like this code

in your custom class make the button action and call the parent method that pass the view tag

ArrayName = Array Hold all the data of the given table actually it save all the view (in this array we save the view that show on cell in other words it store the complete cell)

custom class method like this

```
- (IBAction)button_Action:(UIButton *)sender {
        [parentView Action:self.view.tag BtnTag:sender.tag];
}
```

in parent class

```
 -(void)Remove:(int ) BtnTag  :btnTag
for (int i = 0; i<[ArrayName count]; i++)
{
    customCell *vca=[ArrayName objectAtIndex:i];   
    if(vca.view.tag == viewTag) // here check the cell where we tap or click
    {
         for (UIView* view in [self.view subviews]) {
           if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                 UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)view; 
                     if(btn.tag == btnTag)
                 NSLog(@"You write this your own code what you want to do "); 
                }
              }

    } 
    }
}
```

i hope this solve your problem